# Prisma schema make relation default to latest row id

Tags: mysql, prisma

I'm keeping configuration data versioned in the database with an autoincrement id. I need to reference this relation to the latest version, which looks something like this in the Prisma schema (using `Post` as an example but what I'm using isn't relevant):

```
model Post {
  id               Int           @id @default(uuid())
  title            String
  content          String
  Configuration    Configuration @relation(fields: [configuration_id], references: [id])
  configuration_id Int
}

model Configuration {
  id        Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  format    String
  font_size Float
  Post      Post[]
}
```

I would like to have `configuration_id` in `Post` to default to the id of the newest row of `Configuration`, I've tried doing this:

```
  configuration_id Int  @default(dbgenerated("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Configuration"))
```

But it gives me an error when I run the `prisma push` command:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(id) FROM Configuration, MODIFY `configuration_id` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFA' at line 1
```

I haven't been able to found a solution for this out there, for now I'll just query the id manually before inserting a `Post`, but it would be nice if Prisma could take care of this.

How would I fix this error, or what would be a better solution?

Comment: Instead of directly writing SQL query in dbgenerated, can you create a function that executes this SQL?https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#dbgenerated

Comment: @NurulSundarani sadly no, I get the following error
`Error: Default value expression of column 'id' contains a disallowed function Get_Id`, I'm gonna try using prisma middlewares instead

Comment: You might want to have a look at Prisma Client Extensions: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions

You can achieve everything that you can do in middleware in client extensions, but the extensions are way more powerful